# Web page scraper using Python returns none

Tags: python, web-scraping

Good evening, The below code returns none, however I am expecting to see the product title. I think the title variable is incorrect, however I am not sure what I need to amend.

Any assistance would be great,

Thank you

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Razer-BlackWidow-Lite-Backlighting-Productivity/dp/B07KQR7RLH/ref=sr_1_1?crid=33KIPEXJU7JNK&dchild=1&keywords=blackwidow+lite&qid=1592502185&sprefix=blackwidow%2Caps%2C158&sr=8-1'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# print(soup.prettify())


title = soup.find(id="productTitle")

print(title)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Can you be more specific about what you expect to happen? Have you looked at any of your intermediate variables to see what values they have?

Comment: I have amended the question and title, is this now ok? (very new to this)

Comment: Have you inspected the value of `soup`? Does it contain an element with `id="productTitle"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this out, it may not be able to find the id productTitle without knowing where it is.

```
title  = soup.find('span', {'id':'productTitle'})
```

You could also try:

```
titleSection = soup.find('div', class_='a-section a-spacing-none')
title = titleSection.h1.span.text
```